# Django queryset filter with Q object or relationship is not working as expected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model A with two fields:

```
class A(models.Model):
     text = models.TextField()
     b = models.ForeignKey(
        B, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
     )
```

And a model B:

```
class B(models.Model):
     text = models.TextField()
```

I have a record A with text field "12345" and a b field as null.

When trying to filter model A with:

```
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            models.Q(text__icontains="123") | models.Q(b__text__icontains="123")
        )
```

But the record is filtered out. Did I miss anything?

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: @Jafoor Hi, I expect the the record is not filtered out. Since the first part `text__icontains="123"` is good, even though the foreign key `b` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression

```py
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            models.Q(text__icontains="123") | models.Q(b__text__icontains="123")
        )
```

results in `JOIN` which filters out As having b = NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id WHERE a.text ILIKE "%123%" OR b.text ILIKE "%123%"
```

Try appending manually the records having `b` field unset:

```py
        queryset = (queryset.filter(b__text__icontains="123")
                    | queryset.filter(text__icontains="123"))
```

The second part of query will contain the records with `b=NULL` as long as it doesn't JOIN B with itself

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.b_id = b WHERE b.text ILIKE "%123%"
UNION
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.text ILIKE "%123%"
```

Comment: Hi madbrid, this works! Though it's queryset.union(...). Thanks a lot!